# Why does the function sometimes return 0 and sometimes return False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I made a very simple function in Python 3.9 (`f(x, y, z) = (x and y) or (not x and z)`) that prints the result of this operation. What weirds me out is that in some cases it prints 0 and in some others it prints False. For example, `f(0, 1, 0)` prints 0 but `f(1, 0, 1)` prints False. Why is that?

Comment: Even if you consider it very simple, simplifying further (e.g. trying one side of the `or`, then the other) will help find the answer!

Comment: you an typecast to integer, `(x and y) or (int(not x) and z)`

Answer (score 3):

`and` returns the first value if it's falsey, otherwise it returns the second value. `or` returns the first value if it's truthy, otherwise it returns the second value. So, `and` and `or` won't transmute types. `not`, however, will always convert to a boolean of the opposite truthiness. So, `not 1` becomes `False`, `False and z` becomes `False`, and if `x and y` is not truthy, then the expression will evaluate to `False`. That's why you can get different data types.